# Rails 2 tables, 1 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am relatively new to ruby/rails and I have the following question:

I am working on a scheduling app and have a model named Classes and another named ClassEntries. The relationship between them is that each user can have multiple class entries per semester, each relating to one class. Each record in the Classes table belongs to a specific University. A User can have multiple entries in the ClassEntries table for 1 semester (typically 5). Their schedule is comprised of all their ClassEntries with the same semester ID.

I am not sure whether I should have a third model called Schedule that brings together the info in the ClassEntries and Classes models for the user at hand. I originally wrote this functionality in PHP and I simply used a MySQL JOIN to gather the necessary information. In Rails it seems that there should be a better way to accomplish this.

What would be the best way of going about this in Rails?

Many thanks

Comment: Does your Classes model have a knowledge of semester? There's many ways to go about what you want to do. If you already wrote the PHP functionality then the Rails way should be a breeze.

Comment: Currently I don't have a semester model. Should I? As the records in the Classes table are independent of a semester or schedule, the ClassEntries would need to belong to a semester, right?

Comment: You said you have already implemented this in PHP. What does your database table look like (Models and relationships) Any info on that would help us understand what you are trying to do. I'm still a bit confused what you mean by ClassEntries what exactly entails a ClassEntry? If I understand correctly, a ClassEntry is just just means a User is taking that class in a particular semester?

Comment: Also, I think you will have problems naming a model "Class" as it would cause conflict with Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what a ClassEntry is. It ties together a user, class and semester. If there is a naming conflict, I can rename Class to Course.

In PHP I was executing raw SQL (which I'd rather minimise in rails as much as possible). An example: "SELECT * FROM classentries LEFT JOIN classes ON classentries.class_id = classes.id WHERE classentries.user_id = 1"

Comment: It seems to me that the "rails way" of doing things would suggest that I have some sort of Schedule model rather than using various joins here and there?

Comment: Not necessary, let me write up an answer and see if it helps you we can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

So, what you are looking for is pretty much associations in Rails.

You would have the following:

```
def User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_entries
  has_many :courses, :through => :class_entries
end

def CourseEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end

def Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_entries
  has_many :users, :through => :class_entries
end
```

With those associations set up, Rails would allow you to do such things like
`some_user.courses` or `some_course.users` and it will make the joins through CourseEntry for you.

Let me know if this helps. If you need me to go more in depth let me know.

Comment: Thanks for that. You mention course_entries and class_entries. Are these interchangeable or different entities?

Comment: sorry that's a typo. If the class is named CourseEntry then you should use :course_entries if its named ClassEntries use :class_entries.